# Which of these is bubble sort or they are both?

Tags: c, sorting

These two algorithms sort date in ascending order. Are these 2 sort algorithm are called bubble sort?

1) First it finds the smallest from all entire array by using swap and put it in the index 0, and so on.

Or other words --> After one each iteration it pushes the smallest value at the beginning of array by using swap.

```
for (int i = 0; i != arrayEnd - 1; i++) {
    for (j = i + 1; j != arrayEnd; j++) {
        if (A[i] > A[j]) {
            temp = A[i];
            A[i] = A[j];
            A[j] = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

2) After one each iteration it pushes the biggest value at the end of array by using swap.

```
while (!isSorted) {
    isSorted = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < lastUnsorted; i++) {  // lastUnsorted = arrayLength - 1;
        if (A[i] > A[i + 1]) {
            temp = A[i];
            A[i] = A[i + 1];
            A[i + 1] = temp;
            isSorted = false;
        }
    }
    lastUnsorted--; 
}
```

They are both called bubble sort?

Comment: Theoretically, bubble sort has the largest element *rise like a bubble* to the end after each iteration. There was a name for the algorithm where the smallest element *sinks like a rock* to the beginning, but I can't seem to recall it. Either way they're both the same algorithm.

Comment: The most optimistic interpretation of bubble-sort (one element bubbles to a "sorted" end) is accomplished by both algorithms. However, the actual [bubblesort algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort) compares *adjacent elements*. Furthermore, your second implementation includes swap-detection, an optimization that gives an early exit option. The best-case of O(n) happens with an already-sorted sequence, whereas the first implementation will still be O(N^2).

Answer (score 3):

In both the cases it is obeying the bubblesort, but in the second case the bubble sort made efficient by removing the largest element at the end of the array.

Now, that would still do a lot of unnecessary iterations when the array has a long sorted tail of largest elements, say you have k,k-1,...,1 as the first k elements and k+1 to 100000000 in order after that. The standard Bubble sort will pass k times through (almost) the entire array.

But you can try this in that matter:

```
while(!isSorted){
        isSorted = true;
        int lastSwap = lastUnsorted;
        for (int i = 0; i < lastSwap; i++) {  // lastUnsorted = arrayLength - 1;
            if (A[i] > A[i + 1]) {
                temp = A[i];
                A[i] = A[i + 1];
                A[i + 1] = temp;
                isSorted = false;
                currentSwap = j; 
            }
        }
        lastUnsorted--; 
        lastSwap = currentSwap; 
    }
```

Comment: I think variant 1) and 2) are equal in sense  of efficiency . "In the second case the bubble sort made efficient by removing the largest element at the end of the array", in its turn in the first case the bubble sort made efficient by removing the smallest at the beginning of array. I've tried to test myself by putting swapCounter in both variants and I obtained the same number of swapping in both cases.

Answer (score 2):

Yes - both are bubble sorts variants.
Variant 1) is not optimal - every case is O(N^2)
Variant 2) is better - inner loop every iteration does skip one comparison because it knows one element if at sorted place.

Comment: Variant 1) But outer loop every iteration does skip one comparison because after 1 iteration it sets A[0] and doesnt look there anymore( and inner loop too), after 2 iteration it sets A[1] and doesnt look there anymore  ( and inner loop too) and so on. I think they are equal in this sense. Or I'm wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Classical bubble sort has O(n^2) and Ω(n) asymptotic runtime. it's my 2nd variant.  First variant more resembles to Selection Sort O(n^2)  Ω(n^2) but without finding min value.

By simply saying my 1st variant is less efficient than classical Selection sort although they are very similar.

My answer is No. They are not both bubble sort. Only 2nd is bubble sort.