# Is there a name for my sorting algorithm?

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting

In a school assignment, I was supposed to create a sorting algorithm.

**I did the following:**

```
    //array "ints" has already been declared
    int s = 0;
    for(int i=0;i<ints.length;i++) {
        for(int j=i+1; j<ints.length; j++) {
            if(ints[i]>ints[j]) {
                s = ints[j];
                ints[j]=ints[i];
                ints[i]=s;  
            }
        }
    }
```

The teacher called the above algorithm "bubble sort." However, from what I can find, (on Google) the above code is *not* bubble sort, and **bubble sort looks more like the below code:** (probably not the most efficient version of it, but whatever)

```
    //array "ints" has already been declared
    int sub = 0;
    int swaps = 100;
    if (ints.length>1) {
        while(swaps>0) {
            swaps=0;
            for(int i=0; i<ints.length-1; i++) {
                if(ints[i]>ints[i+1]) {
                    sub = ints[i+1];
                    ints[i+1]=ints[i];
                    ints[i]=sub;
                    swaps++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I'm certain that I didn't actually invent a new sorting algorithm, but I can't find any sorting algorithm that uses the same process as the code that I wrote.

Is there a name for my algorithm?

**Note that it compares non-adjacent values and the sorting process and the algorithm does not necessarily finish after a round of going through the algorithm without swapping.** Both of these indicate that it is *not* bubble sort. It's possibly a version selection sort.

---

*I don't want to know how efficient it is; I'm working on finding that out on my own.*

Comment: It **is** Bubble Sort.

Comment: @PM77-1 oh. I was under the impression that Bubble sort only compared _adjacent_ values like [here](https://mathbits.com/MathBits/Java/arrays/Bubble.htm).

Comment: There's more than 1 way to implement Bubble sort. Bubble sort is simply bubbling of low values to the top.

Comment: @Srini thanks. So is the link I mentioned wrong to say "_The bubble sort repeatedly compares adjacent elements of an array._"? Or are they saying that _their_ bubble sort works like that?

Comment: See a similar question maybe: [Which of these is bubble sort or they are both?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42178562/which-of-these-is-bubble-sort-or-they-are-both)

Comment: okay, I see what you are getting at,  It is not *traditional* Bubble sort. What you have implemented is I'd say similar to a slight modification to Bubble sort called *Selection Sort*, more [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/selection-sort/). You iterate over sub arrays to find the min in Selection sort.

Comment: @Srini would you mind putting that in an answer?

Comment: It is more like selection sort with a lot of superfluous swaps in my opinion.

Comment: @unlut the question you linked has conflicting answers :(

Comment: @maraca yeah I didn't think it was very efficient. Based on the link from unlut, I'm guessing that it's more like selection sort.

Comment: @firephil from the first link you gave - Bubble Sort "compares adjacent pairs". My algorithm (probably modified selection sort) can compare non-adjacent values.

Comment: @firephil what do those links prove? All examples of bubble sort just compare and swap *adjacent* elements like Brandon_J said at the very beginning.

Comment: @firephil yes, but that is not in my example.

Comment: but ints[i]>ints[j] isn't, like I said, some weird in-place selection sort that requires superfluous swaps.

Comment: @firephil and i and j are not always different by only one ( ints[i]>ints[i+1] is not the same as ints[i]>ints[j] )

Comment: @firephil and then j++, multiple times if it is a large array. (what maraca says below)

Comment: @firephil no look closer, only on the first iteration of the inner loop

Comment: And I know that this question is basic; the thing is, (besides my understanding of compsci being basic ATM) it's easy to go from algorithm name to algorithm. It's harder to go from algorithm to algorithm name.

Comment: @Brandon_J you can call it a hybrid bubble-Selection Sort it's not a clean Selection Sort or Bubble Sort

Comment: @firephil perhaps. The basic procedure seems far closer to Selection Sort IMO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be a modified [selection sort](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/selection-sort/), as pointed out by maraca and Srini.

See, for example, [this animation page](https://www.toptal.com/developers/sorting-algorithms). Bubble Sort (with a given array/list length) takes longer or shorter depending on whether the array is nearly sorted or not. Selection Sort (with a given array/list length) takes the *exact same amount of time* regardless of how sorted the list was originally. My algorithm is basically like selection sort, except that it has a lot of extra/unnecessary swaps.

Comment: When I learned this idiom in school the professor called it a selection sort. Both of which are pretty terrible sorting algorithms but there's a solid argument to be made whether it's a worse selection sort, or worse bubble sort.